# How to reduce minor-faults?

Tags: c, linux, performance, x86-64, linux-device-driver

My binary is about 3MB which can easily fit in L3 cache. I call mmap (and malloc) as early as possible so the OS has time to get the pages ready for my program. A few places I tried allocating more to minimize reallocs. Yet in a 1 second run I'll get 11K minor-faults

I tried using `perf` with fault and cache-misses to narrow down where my problems are. I don't seem to understand it. Many seems to happen on a 64byte structure. I wrote a bump allocator for it, then switched from malloc (no realloc used) to mmap. Changed it to allocate the entire size to see how it'd perform. I still had 11K faults

What are minor faults and why am I getting 11K of them per second?

Comment: Minor page-faults are ones that don't require any I/O to correct, e.g. copy-on-write or lazy allocation (like the first time you touch a page from mmap without MAP_POPULATE).  Linux does wire multiple pages on one page fault (fault-around), but still like maybe 1 fault per 8 or 16 pages touched if you're looping over a huge array from malloc or mmap.

Comment: @PeterCordes is there a way to tell it I'll need a lot more? Maybe I can use MAP_POPULATE on a background thread to allocate 1G then hand it out to my threads as needed. The kernel is about 10% of my CPU time and most of the cache misses seem to be in kernel functions

Comment: @Stan: Have you tried `madvise(..., MADV_WILLNEED)`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I completely forgot. It seems to decrease the amount of faults but time taken didn't seem to change.

Comment: But anyway, why do you believe it's important to bring this number down?  What evidence do you have that it's a metric of something having a significant impact on your program's performance?  You say "11K faults per second", but it sounds like that means your program takes 1 second to run and has 11K faults.  Does it actually scale linearly when your program runs for longer without using more memory?  It could be it's a "one-time cost" on startup.

Comment: In other words, if something like madvise doesn't decrease the time taken, then maybe memory population didn't take a significant amount of time in the first place.  So if you're looking for a speedup, perhaps you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @NateEldredge trying it again I see no difference with madvise. I'll spread it out to see if that helps. I gained 100ms by using a bigger mmap size in a few places. perf also says I have >10% of my CPU time in kernel related fault functions

Comment: Page fault overheads needs to be paid. You can move their location but this will not much impact the execution time. Recycling allocated memory is a good way to reduce the number of page fault in many cases. You can also try to enforce the use of huge pages regarding your needs, but AFAIK transparent huge pages should already be used when you allocate a big block of memory. AFAIR, the default glibc allocator on Linux tends to be conservative so it tends not to give the allocated memory back to the OS (except in rare cases or maybe huge chunks).